# Windows Python 3.10 embedded pip No module named 'src'

Tags: python-3.x, spleeter

Trying to get pip to install Spleeter using Python embedded on Windows.
After diving down many rabbit holes i need some guidance.
I have tried this and get the same error with Pythons 3.7.9, 3.8.10, 3.9.13, 3.10.11 (all currently supported versions for Spleeter)
I am trying to build a new Python folder for my SpleeterGUI OS project. Another user has hosted the current Python files, a friend of mine put it together but i can't replicate it with newer python versions. search github for thooore/SpleeterCore

I have downloaded and extracted
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.11/python-3.10.11-embed-amd64.zip
Edited python310._pth, added "Lib\site-packages" to line 3
Here's what happened...

```
C:\temp\spleeter>cd 3.10.11

C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11>curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11>python.exe get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Obtaining dependency information for pip from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/c2/e06851e8cc28dcad7c155f4753da8833ac06a5c704c109313b8d5a62968a/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Obtaining dependency information for setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/26/7945080113158354380a12ce26873dd6c1ebd88d47f5bc24e2c5bb38c16a/setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Obtaining dependency information for wheel from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/8b/31273bf66016be6ad22bb7345c37ff350276cfd46e389a0c2ac5da9d9073/wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Using cached pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (807 kB)
Using cached wheel-0.41.2-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The script wheel.exe is installed in 'C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.10.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip setuptools wheel


C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11>python.exe -m pip install spleeter
Collecting spleeter
  Obtaining dependency information for spleeter from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/59/c43fe99b90514e2444ae3aa5fdbb7bc33041aa1763c979fe74d4216dd5e4/spleeter-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached spleeter-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting ffmpeg-python<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached ffmpeg_python-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting httpx[http2]<0.20.0,>=0.19.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached httpx-0.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting norbert<0.3.0,>=0.2.1 (from spleeter)
  Using cached norbert-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pandas<2.0.0,>=1.3.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (10.4 MB)
Collecting tensorflow<2.10.0,>=2.5.0 (from spleeter)
  Using cached tensorflow-2.9.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (444.2 MB)
Collecting typer<0.4.0,>=0.3.2 (from spleeter)
  Using cached typer-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting future (from ffmpeg-python<0.3.0,>=0.2.0->spleeter)
  Using cached future-0.18.3.tar.gz (840 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z80119wi\future_fd492dd3e5934f9b85432f175479d227\setup.py", line 86, in <module>
          import src.future
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried Python embedded 3.7.9, 3.8.10, 3.9.13, 3.10.11
Calling pip directly .\Scripts\pip install spleeter

Setting environment
C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11>set PY_PIP=python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\Scripts
C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11>set PY_LIBS=python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\Lib;python-3.10.11-embed-amd64\Lib\site-packages

If i try install package "src"...
python.exe -m pip install src

```
Collecting src
  Using cached src-0.0.7.zip (6.3 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: src
  Building wheel for src (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      creating build\lib\src
      copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib\src
      running egg_info
      writing src.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      deleting src.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to src.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.rst'
      writing manifest file 'src.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:947: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
              standards-based tools.

              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        command.initialize_options()
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hnihey52\src_32ac933409b24581846526dac14fc81e\setup.py", line 70, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 366, in run
          install = self.reinitialize_command("install", reinit_subcommands=True)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 216, in reinitialize_command
          cmd = _Command.reinitialize_command(self, command, reinit_subcommands)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 311, in reinitialize_command
          return self.distribution.reinitialize_command(command, reinit_subcommands)
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 953, in reinitialize_command
          for sub in command.get_sub_commands():
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 329, in get_sub_commands
          if method is None or method(self):
        File "C:\temp\spleeter\3.10.11\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 787, in has_lib
          self.distribution.has_pure_modules() or self.distribution.has_ext_modules()
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_pure_modules'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for src
  Running setup.py clean for src
Failed to build src
ERROR: Could not build wheels for src, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: src is not a package. So, you can't install it. There might be a problem with the pakage itself.

Comment: Follow the installation procedure listed here - https://pypi.org/project/spleeter/

Comment: This is for Python embedded. Can't do a conda/other install method.  I believe it's an evironment issue, but can't make sense of venv with Python embedded...or even if it would help.

Comment: SOLVED: Just in case you run in to this problem. The embedded version of python is not configured to run pip, so you will have many issues.  you need to get both windows installer and embedded [same version] and use the installed version to pip install using --target and target the embedded directory.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Just in case you run in to this problem. The embedded version of python is not configured to run pip, so you will have many issues. you need to get both windows installer and embedded [same version] and use the installed version to pip install using --target and target the embedded directory.